# Using geolocation API in local server

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, geolocation

I'm trying to use the Geolocation WebAPI but both Firefox and Chrome say that I'm working in unsafe environment and I can't make it work.

I'm using Apache2 under Ubuntu 18 and I've created a VirtualHost named **test.local** and added to hosts file.

I know that localhost is marked as *secure environment* but I want to use the friendly url.